# Datatable Server Side com JOIN

Tags: php, jquery-datatables, datatable

Boa noite!

Comecei a usar Datatable recentemente, estou usando com o recurso server-side. Preciso relacionar 2 tabelas com INNER JOIN, vi que existe uma "dificuldade" em fazer esse tipo de procedimento no caso do server-side. Até encontrei uma ssp.class.php customizada, mas não entendi bem como usa-la...

Alguém teria um tutorial pra compartilhar sobre o assunto? Ou algum exemplo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ao utilizar a opção server-side, você vai ter que adaptar o seu código no lado do servidor para receber e retornar os valores em uma estrutura definida pelas requisições do DataTables.

O DataTables envia para o servidor os dados com essa estrutura mais ou menos:

- **start:** se tiver usando paginação, você vai ter que retornar somente as linhas da tabela que serão exibidas, então o start é o limite inferior da busca no banco
- **length**: a partir do start, quantas linhas pra frente eu vou retornar, ou seja, o número de itens que serão exibidos em uma página
- **draw**: um número de controle que serve para o DataTables saber em que página está, você vai apenas retornar ele de volta
- **order**: um array com colunas e direção (ascendente, descendente) que você irá usar na consulta para fazer a ordenação da tabela
- **search**: um array com valores que você usará para fazer buscas na tabela, ou seja, o WHERE da consulta
- **columns**: as colunas da tabela

Além disso, o DataTables espera também uma resposta com essa estrutura:

- **draw:** valor de controle de página para o DataTables
- **recordsTotal:** número total de linhas da sua tabela no banco sem filtros (um count(*) sem WHERE)
- **recordsFiltered:** número total de linhas da consulta com filtros. Se não tiver sido feito nenhum filtro (busca por valores específicos), então será o mesmo valor do **recordsTotal**
- **data:** um array de chaves e valores com o retorno da sua consulta.

Você vai retornar tudo isso em um JSON. O JSON pode ter outros dados conforme sua necessidade, mas esses dados citados são obrigatórios pra tabela funcionar corretamente com paginação e tudo mais.

Sabendo essa estrutura, agora você tem que montar suas consultas utilizando o start, length, search, sort, etc. O fato de você fazer um JOIN na sua busca não faz diferença nesse caso, ele funciona com qualquer consulta. Sugiro que você veja o código [dessa página](https://github.com/coderexample/datatable_example/blob/master/demo1/employee-grid-data.php), ele mostra um exemplo de como fazer isso com MySQL, utilizando a estrutura que falei, de forma mais simples do que o **ssp.class.php** que você citou. [Esse vídeo no YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F474RINIYYk) também explica de forma bastante clara. Boa sorte!